# Aggregate in memory incoming messages from IoT Hub for function app to perform calculations of the resulting batch

Tags: azure-functions, azure-iot-hub, azure-durable-functions, azure-eventgrid

I receive into IoT Hub incoming messages from MCU sensors and route these to Event Grid on to a function app (telemetryfunction) which I think keeps the incoming messages in order as when received.

[image]

[image]

I would like to aggregate these messages received in the function app as a batch of e.g. 5/10 to then run an algorithm on these.

I don't see how I can store on memory the incoming messages received in the function app to then run the algorithms/methods for the accumulated resulting batch.

I would like to avoid using a database and rather hold the data on memory because of the speed at which individual incoming messages are received (10ms). I looked at [durable functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp) but I don't see that would help me store data in memory or queue the messages to create a batch, can someone point me in the right direction please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Event Grid does not not [guarantee ordering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/delivery-and-retry?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034).

You can [connect your Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-iot?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034) to the Event Hub endpoint of the IoT Hub and use the batch feature. However, you can only specify the max number of items in a batch, not a minimum. This could result in batches of 1-n messages, where n is your maximum.

Another option is to use Azure Stream Analytics. It supports batching of input events, but all the [options are temporal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-window-functions?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034). This means you can't specify how big your batch should be, just how big the timeframe is. This might be a match with your use-case though!